# Using Google maps API nearBysearch with multiple types

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, search, types

So I am working with google maps API in Javascript and my code for searching looks like this:

```
therequest = {
bounds: map.getBounds(),
type: 'Cafe',
};

service.nearbySearch(therequest, callback);
```

I want to search for multiple types in one search and I know you can use:

```
types: ['Cafe','bar']
```

But according to google documentation this method will stop being supported at the start of next year. Is there a replacement method for achieving a similar search or would you just have to loop over the searches with different requests?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, I think Google not yet released the alternative way/replacement for that parameter. It only says in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#deprecation) that,

> The implementation for types in text search requests is changing. The
>   types parameter is deprecated as of February 16, 2016, replaced by a
>   new type parameter which only supports one type per search request. 
>   Requests using the deprecated features will be supported until
>   February 16, 2017, after which all text searches must use the new
>   implementation.

So we still have one year to use it, Also maybe Google might extend that period like they do on the id and reference field that supposedly deprecated on June 24, 2014. They extend it one more year because they are looking into ways of ensuring this change will not break the existing code. Just an opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a request with ajax for example to (specifying the output and the parameters) :

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/output?parameters

See the docs :

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests

Comment: Yes but that would still be using the 'types' item which will be depreciated next year?